# Jenkins Pipeline "yarn install" command not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is my first Jenkins script, it currently operates well on Linux but I migrate to MacOS (High Sierra) with the result of getting shell script error.

Node and yarn packages are installed on local Jenkins user. I can't figure out why this error just happens, could anyone give me a hand on this?

Here is my Jenkins file:

```
node {
  stage('Check out') {
    checkout scm
  }
  stage('Prepare') {
    sh "yarn install"
  }
  stage('Test') {
    sh "yarn test"
  }
  stage('Sonar') {
    if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'dev') {
      def scannerHome = tool 'sonar scanner';
      withSonarQubeEnv('sonar') {
        sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And full log:

> 14:43:11 Connecting to https://api.github.com using hariklee/******
>
> Obtained Jenkinsfile from 6c639bd70ac86cbe6a49ac0b58bcc10e3c64a375
>
> Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
>
> [Pipeline] node
>
> Running on Jenkins in 
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/wingman_423_ci_cd-7PSSGRAMBTXUQRESYCNVODXU7IZJLJLPHQOE3KYEPCSAAYAFFD4A
>
> [Pipeline] {
>
> [Pipeline] stage
>
> [Pipeline] { (Check out)
>
> [Pipeline] checkout
>
> > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
> >     Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> >
> > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/wingman-xyz/app.git # timeout=10
>
> Fetching without tags
>
> Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/wingman-xyz/app.git
>
> > git --version # timeout=10
>
> using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials
>
> > git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/wingman-xyz/app.git +refs/heads/423_ci_cd:refs/remotes/origin/423_ci_cd
>
> Checking out Revision 6c639bd70ac86cbe6a49ac0b58bcc10e3c64a375 (423_ci_cd)
>
> > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> >
> > git checkout -f 6c639bd70ac86cbe6a49ac0b58bcc10e3c64a375
>
> Commit message: "jenkins test"
>
> First time build. Skipping changelog.
>
> [Pipeline] }
>
> [Pipeline] // stage
>
> [Pipeline] stage
>
> [Pipeline] { (Prepare)
>
> [Pipeline] sh
>
> [wingman_423_ci_cd-7PSSGRAMBTXUQRESYCNVODXU7IZJLJLPHQOE3KYEPCSAAYAFFD4A] Running shell script
>
> - yarn install
>
> /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/wingman_423_ci_cd-7PSSGRAMBTXUQRESYCNVODXU7IZJLJLPHQOE3KYEPCSAAYAFFD4A@tmp/durable-cf573520/script.sh: line 2: yarn: command not found
>
> [Pipeline] }
>
> [Pipeline] // stage
>
> [Pipeline] }
>
> [Pipeline] // node
>
> [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
>
> GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result
>
> ERROR: script returned exit code 127
>
> Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no `yarn` command in your `PATH` variable. 
Do `npm install -g yarn` before

```
stage('Prepare') {
    sh "npm install -g yarn"
    sh "yarn install"
}
```

If you get an error about not found `npm` command then you will have to add npm explicitly to your `PATH` using [`withEnv() {}`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-withenv-code-set-environment-variables)

```
withEnv(['PATH+NODE=/something=/path/to/node/bin']) {
        stage('Prepare') {
        sh "npm install -g yarn"
        sh "yarn install"
    }
}
```

Comment: It really works if `withEnv() {}` is added. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Installation of Yarn via npm is generally not recommended. When installing Yarn with Node-based package managers, the package is not signed, and the only integrity check performed is a basic SHA1 hash, which is a security risk when installing system-wide apps. See more about: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#alternatives-stable

Comment: Weird, it seems like yarn is installed: `+ yarn@1.7.0
added 1 package in 0.613s` but when running `yarn <my command>`, I still have `script.sh: line 2: yarn: command not found`

Comment: @belgoros do you execute yarn in the same `withEnv([...]) {}` block?

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko, yes, sure.

Comment: How do I find the node path?